# Colocacion de valor NO constante en arreglos

Tags: c++, loops, array

Buenas noches, trato de crear un programa en C++ que combine arreglos en for y switch; sin embargo, me marca error en la declaración de la variable números[p], sé que es debido a que el numero entre los corchetes debe ser una constante. Mi pregunta es, ¿existe alguna manera de declarar un valor NO constante dentro de los corchetes? De antemano, gracias.

```
#include <iostream>

int n,p,c,numero;
int numeros[p];

using namespace std;

{
    void CrearArreglo()
{
    {
        cout<<"Inserta el numero de indices que quieres que tenga tu arreglo (entre 5 y 20)"<<endl;
        cin>>n;
    }
}
void LlenarArreglo()
{
    int numeros[p];
    for(int p=0;p<n;p++)
    {
        cout<<"Introduce un numero"<<endl;
        cin>>numero;
        numeros[p]=numero;
    }
}
int main()
{
    do{
    cout<<"Elige una opcion"<<endl;
    cout<<"0 Salir"<<endl;
    cout<<"1 Crear arreglo"<<endl;
    cout<<"2 Llenar arreglo"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    switch(c)
   {
        case 1:
               {
                   CrearArreglo();
               }
        break;
        case 2:
               {
                   LlenarArreglo();
               }
        break;
}
}while(c!=0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Existe alguna manera de declarar un valor NO constante dentro de los corchetes?

Suponiendo que te refieras a **usar** un valor no constante (los valores constantes no se *declaran dentro de corchetes*), lo puedes hacer en dos situaciones:

#### 1.- Arreglos de tamaño dinámico (AtD).

Conocidos como [Variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) en inglés no forman parte del estándar de C++ pero algunos compiladores les dan soporte como extensión al compilador. Si dicha extensión está activada se puede usar un valor no constante para definir el tamaño de un arreglo:

```
int p;
std::cin >> p;
int numeros[p]; /* Valido si la extension AtD existe y esta activada.
                   no valido en caso contrario! */
```

Dado que esta opción es dependiente del compilador, resulta no ser [portable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portabilidad) y por ello se desaconseja su uso.

#### 2.- Arreglos definidos en tiempo de ejecución.

Si reservas la memoria dinámicamente, es posible usar una variable para el tamaño del arreglo:

```
int p;
std::cin >> p;
int *numeros new int[p];
//                   ^ <-- esto no es una constante!
```

No olvides borrar la memoria cuando ya no la necesites:

```
delete []numeros;
```

O mejor, usa punteros inteligentes:

```
int p;
std::cin >> p;
auto numeros = std::make_unique<int[]>(p);
//       esto no es una constante! --> ^

for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
    numeros[i] = i; // Se usa como un arreglo normal
```

Answer (score 6):

Tu pregunta es:

> ¿existe alguna manera de declarar un valor NO constante dentro de los
>   corchetes?

Y la respuesta es **NO**.

La dimensión de un `array` debe ser una constante de valor conocido al compilar, obligatoriamente. Para reservar una porción de memoria libre definida durante la ejecución, debes usar `new` (o algún contenedor apropiado de la biblioteca estándar).

*Comentario:*
Bueno, no tomar este NO en forma taxativa; hay algún compilador que lo acepta como extensión al lenguaje.

Comment: @eferion Sí, de acuerdo, hay compiladores que incluyen extensiones al lenguaje, como el caso del gcc y las VLA, pero creo que son casos marginales. Supongo que agregar un comentario que diga algo así como "Bueno, no tomar este `NO` en forma taxativa; hay algún compilador que lo acepta como extensión al lenguaje" sería suficiente. Hecho.